# How to convert the text file in json by using in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My text file `test.txt` contains `2234#2#"Rama is god"#abcd#2`(this is in line 1 sentence)

I need to convert this into `json`
like this

```
 snumber => 2234, 
 revision =>2
 msg => "rama is god" 
 se => "abcd"
 number =>2
```

Comment: That's not JSON. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I made an edit, but not sure how it looks in your mind. Edit if something is wrong.

Comment: sir how to convert text file into JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-split)  to parse the line, create a hash from it, which you can convert to JSON;

```
require 'json'

text = IO.read('test.txt')
snumber, revision, msg, se, number = text.split('#')
# => ["2234", "2", "\"Rama is god\"", "abcd", "2"]

target_hash = {snumber: snumber.to_i, revision: revision.to_i , msg: msg.downcase[1..-2], se: se, number: number.to_i }
# => {:snumber=>2234, :revision=>2, :msg=>"rama is god", :se=>"abcd", :number=>2}

puts JSON.pretty_generate target_hash
# {
#   "snumber": 2234,
#   "revision": 2,
#   "msg": "rama is god",
#   "se": "abcd",
#   "number": 2
# }
```